# Spring Boot How to delegate resources to CDN?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cdn, cloudflare

In spring boot , I include my own css or js like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/static/css/main.css}"/>
<script th:src="@{/static/js/modernizr.js}"></script>
<img th:src="@{/static/images/home_user.jpg}" />
```

The generated html like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/static/css/main-c9079afb84af98a640f97fbed5759777.css" />
<script src="/static/js/modernizr-bf2f96e6233de3d8c0346085ac28248a.js"></script>
<img src="/static/images/home_user-378972abb38069e9b18d9637bc052e3c.jpg">
```

Spring will sign these files and append signatures as filename. It works well , every HTTP request will hit spring and serve these CSS/JS files. But I hope these css/js or **even webjar** resources be served by CDN.

I apply a `cloudflare` account , adding a `static.mysite.com` as `A` address, and point to my server , like this :

[image: cloudflare]

All `static.mysite.com` request will go to cloudflare first , and hit my server if not found.

I hope spring boot will `prepend` all `static` resources (JS/CSS/webjars) to `http://static.mysite.com/` , so that the output HTML will become like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://static.mysite.com/static/css/main-c9079afb84af98a640f97fbed5759777.css" />
<script src="http://static.mysite.com/static/js/modernizr-bf2f96e6233de3d8c0346085ac28248a.js"></script>
<img src="http://static.mysite.com/static/images/home_user-378972abb38069e9b18d9637bc052e3c.jpg">
```

but I don't know how to accomplish this.

Can somebody give some hint ? Thanks.

Spring Boot 1.4.5

(Please correct me if it is not a good idea)